# ADAL (AAD) cookie gets expired or deleted. How to create the cookie?

Tags: angular, cookies, active-directory, adal

I am using ADAL framework to authenticate the users in a single page application (Angular 1.4.8). Sometimes tokens are not generating for the endpoints which I configured as shown below (config object having all the required values).

```
 adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
            {
                instance: config.Instance,
                tenant: config.Tenant,
                clientId: config.ClientId,
                extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
                endpoints: endpoints,
                cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                frameRedirectUri: window.location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/IFrame.html"
            }, $httpProvider);
```

When I am requesting any api call through `$http`, api call is not initiating because token was not generated to the respective resource. In my localStorage I am getting the following error:

> Error: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).

I thought that whenever ADAL is trying to acquiring tokens for the resources, it is failing due to cookie gets deleted/expired. Hence tokens are not generated.

I have tried one approach like whenever I get this error I redirect to the login page (ex: `authContext.login()`), but this leads to an infinite loop of authentications.

I am getting above error in ie, edge, chrome, safari, mobile browses as well.
Can any one tell me how to fix this issue please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to edit your question to make it more easily readable, for example by setting the error message in a quote environment.

Comment: When you try to login(), which is likely the correct action, what is the request/response you're seeing?  Try using a network tracer and look at the request/responses for more info.